# SSL for Phoenix working locally but not on production

Tags: ssl, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an Phoenix/Elixir App that works fine with https locally, however when I try to change it to use the production certificates the server does not respond and no error messages are shown.

[In my dev.exs this was made with the hostname localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvYW1.png)

[In prod.exs here are the keys. These were made with my production URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOO7N.png)

I have tried to change the localhost to production url on local by adding host into the https portion in the config

```
https: [port: 443,
      host: "produrl.com"
      keyfile: "priv/keys/domain.key",
      certfile: "priv/keys/domain.crt"],
```

This throws an error
 `sudo MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server
[info] Running LiteChartBe.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://localhost:80
[info] Application lite_chart_be exited: LiteChartBe.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: LiteChartBe.Endpoint
    ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server
        ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: {:ranch_listener_sup, LiteChartBe.Endpoint.HTTPS}
            ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: :ranch_acceptors_sup
                ** (EXIT) :badarg
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,lite_chart_be,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.LiteChartBe.Endpoint',{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.Server',{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,{ranch_listener_sup,'Elixir.LiteChartBe.Endpoint.HTTPS'},{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,badarg}}}}}}}},{'Elixir.LiteChartBe',start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,lite_chart_be,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.LiteChartBe.Endpoint',{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Phoeni`

If I simply forward localhost to produrl in my local hosts file, no errors are thrown and nothing connects to the server using https.

Answer (score 1):

The error states that you provided a wrong argument for the configuration of your Endpoint (`** (EXIT) :badarg`). I suppose that is beacause you are missing a comma behind your host url.

This does probably not solve your problem, but that is supposedly the reason for the error message shown after your change.